# I have 23 reputation points, but I cannot chat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, chat

On superuser.com I have 23 reputation points. However, I get a message saying that I need 20 reputation points to chat.

The chat room is Super User -> *[Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access)*.

Answer (score 16):

Your chat account is all kinds of messed up in the aftermath of your previous... shenanigans.

We can fix it for you if you use the "contact us" link & write a nice note explaining how you're absolutely NOT gonna do any of the stuff you *were* doing. Otherwise, probably best you stay out of chat.